# Facebook Continued Flow Lead Ads: How to get whitelisted?

Tags: facebook, facebook-marketing-api

We'd like to use the [Facebook Continued Flow Lead Ads API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/guides/lead-ads/continued-flow/v2.6). Integrating it into our website was quite easy. The [Continued Flow Test Tool](https://damp-headland-9382.herokuapp.com/testcontinuedflow) was helpful.
The last step missing is how to integrate our endpoint - the *Follow Up URL* - in campaigns.

In the Facebook Continued Flow Lead Ads API, the documentation says that

> *This feature is available by whitelist only.*

Since Facebook's support doesn't provide this information, maybe someone over here can help me?

How does one get whitelisted?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you have to go through an internal process with a FB account manager or one of the technical managers of the Lead Ads project to get your ad account whitelisted for continued flow use. I checked if this might be exposed on the FB App Review process but it's not yet, so I recommend contacting your account manager if you have one or otherwise trying to go through FB support.

Comment: Thanks @bjeavons for confirming - I already assumed it would be a similar workflow.

Answer (score 0):

in order to be whitelisted you need to have:

- Managed account
- $50K+ monthly spent

Comment: This is false - we have gotten access without spending $50k / month. Please apply through their link (available on the facebook app dashboard).

Answer (score 0):

You can apply through this link which is available publicly - https://www.facebook.com/business/standardadsapi